# URL mod rewrite in Yii Framework

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, yii

This is the original URL in my project

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?r=profile/publicProfile&name=CompanyName
```

But I want to rewrite the URL look like

```
http://www.example.com/CompanyName
```

And, I need to rewrite the URL only for above URL. No need to rewrite all URLs in the project.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters

Comment: Can you try this extension: https://github.com/sensorario/sensorario-url-route ?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Yii URL management is quite handy, you should simply try to modify your urlManager config, e.g. :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
  'showScriptName'=>false,
  'rules'=>array(
    .....
    // AFTER other rules
    '<name>' => 'profile/publicProfile',
```

Don't forget to create a `.htaccess` file to enable rewrite on your server : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x

Comment: But, It apply to all urls.

Comment: I need mod rewrite to only one URl which I have mentioned.

Comment: It does not apply to all urls, you just have to use default rules for other urls